# Publishing non-web SQL based application over Internet

Tags: windows, publish, sharing, smb, non-web

I have a Microsoft SQL based application which has shared among client via Windows shared folder. Each client runs application by clicking a shortcut to main executable file in this shared folder. The group of client are in the same local network and all client runs the app and works fine.

As far as my app has no web-UI for remote users, my question is that if I am going to share this app for remote clients over Internet, do I have to separately forward ports to both SQL server and Windows sharing service (SMB)? Or it would work if I only make Windows folder available for remote user? What would be the best practice for the purpose of file sharing over Internet? Whether exe image in remote CPU will contact other modules in server local? If the server can read/write SQL db on behalf of remote client?

Comment: For this aim we should virtualize our app and then share it over internet. a virtualization technology such as app-v or Xenn-app or similar should be used to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice right now is considered creating a web API (maybe rest) that the client would use to update data on the server. Exposing an SQL server directly to internet is insecure and possibly hard to pass firewall and proxy servers.